# Validate a number 1-100 (do-while loop)

Tags: powershell

I need to make a do-while loop that validates a number is 1-100.
I was able to accomplish this with a do until loop but I'm stuck with the do while.

```
do {
    try {
        $numOk = $true
        $Grade = [int]$final = Read-host "Whats the grade for $student must be 0-100"
        } # end try
    catch {$numOK = $false}
    } # end do 
until (($final -ge 1 -and $final -le 100) -and $numOK)
```

Comment: Are you having trouble inverting the Boolean expression in the condition?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two approaches to negate a boolean expression.

The first is to just put a not operator in front of the original Boolean expression :

```
do {
    try {
        $numOk = $true
        $Grade = [int]$final = Read-host "Whats the grade for $student must be 0-100"
        } # end try
    catch {$numOK = $false}
    } # end do 
while (!(($final -ge 1 -and $final -le 100) -and $numOK))
```

The second is a little more complex but easy to learn. All you must do is negate every operator according the following table :

```
-eq  -> -ne
-ne  -> -eq
-gt  -> -le
-lt  -> -ge
-le  -> -gt
-ge  -> -lt
-and -> -or
-or  -> -and
!    -> !     # These ones remain intact
-not -> -not
```

It gives :

```
do {
    try {
        $numOk = $true
        $Grade = [int]$final = Read-host "Whats the grade for $student must be 0-100"
        } # end try
    catch {$numOK = $false}
    } # end do 
while (($final -lt 1 -or $final -gt 100) -or !$numOK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simplify it greatly.

```
while(1..100 -notcontains $Grade){
    $Grade = Read-host "Whats the grade for $student must be 0-100"
}

Write-Host You entered $Grade for $student
```

or specifically with Do

```
do{
    $Grade = Read-host "Whats the grade for $student must be 0-100"
}
while(1..100 -notcontains $Grade)

Write-Host You entered $Grade for $student
```